# Error : "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" with Foreign keys on Laravel8

Tags: php, laravel-8, factory, seed

I want to write a correct PostFactory for seed my DB with Laravel8

I follow the documentation on Laravel8 for make my Factory for seed my database

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding#using-model-factories

I have 3 Models :

- Category.php
- Post.php
- User.php

I can seed my DB when i use this command :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder
php artisan db:seed --class=CategorySeeder
```

But i can't seed :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=PostSeeder
```

`php artisan db:seed` for seed all DB with one command

My PostSeeder :

```
class PostSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Post::factory(50)->create();
    }
}
```

My PostFactory :

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->faker->sentence(rand(5, 10)),
        'content' => $this->faker->sentences(50, true),
        'image' => 'https://via.placeholder.com/350/65' . rand(1, 100),
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
        'category_id' => Category::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'users_id' => User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
    ];
}
```

My PostFactory does'nt want to take my seed

I encounter this error :

```
 PS C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Laravel_Projects\Blog> php artisan db:seed 

   ErrorException 

  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

  at C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Laravel_Projects\Blog\database\factories\
     28▕             'content' => $this->faker->sentences(50, true),
     29▕             'image' => 'https://via.placeholder.com/350/65' 
     30▕             'created_at' => now(),
     31▕             'updated_at' => now(),

  1   C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Laravel_Projects\Blog\database\factories\PostFactory.php:32
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Trying to get property 'id' of non-object", "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Laravel_Projects\Blog\database\factories\PostFactory.php", [])

  2   C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Laravel_Projects\Blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php:424        
      Database\Factories\PostFactory::definition()
```

My problem come with my 2 foreign keys :
I see the other post with this error but i can't debug with a dd();

I don't found how write my definition for my 2 foreign keys

I have try to check() my id but it'same result.

And to seed my posts_table after and before my users_table and catergories_table it's same.

I tried things with the different posts on the subject without success..Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what `Category::inRandomOrder()->first()` returns?

Comment: Yes, I encounter this error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null"

Comment: But it's logic my categories and users table is empty but it's same with my table categories and users contains data...

Comment: Whatever all that means: if `Category::inRandomOrder()->first()` does not return any entity, it's obvious that this won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the random id it is create random id and how many create record so you define in your seeder.this two line add on your post factory. i hope help you.

```
'category_id' => Category::all()->random()->id,
'users_id' => User::all()->random()->id,
```

Comment: Same problem, but i found an other problem with my databaseSeeder :

Bad Method Call: Did you mean App\Models\Post::setConnection() ?

Comment: public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            Post::class,
            Category::class,
            User::class,
        ]);
    }

Can import the order of my Seeders in this file,
I end up with an error related to the first seeder written in my code

Comment: Ok i change the position of my Factory in my call and it's work => PS C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Laravel_Projects\Blog> php artisan db:seed --class=PostSeeder    
Database seeding completed successfully. But i can't run the command : php artisan db:seed => this doesn't work !

Comment: i do seed my Factory separeted one by one... it's Ok for a little database but not convenient for a Big database...

Comment: $this->call(PostSeeder::class); add on your dadabase seeder.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, when I saw the doc, I thought I should write my Models and not my Seeders... it works, thank you!

Comment: most welcome this answer will be help for you so up this answer another people can use for that. thank you.